# How to pass the variable to having statement in stored procedure - MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm new to store procedure when I query separate the queries are working fine but I use inside of stored procedure it triggers an error.

It's not an error, Output should be the NULL value. The rowt value not created and I'm using having condition in the second query. Due to rowt null, the whole query triggers null value.

The result I got was purchase and others or null.

```
DELIMITER ;;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_purchase;
Create Procedure sp_purchase(
 IN start_date INT,
 IN mail varchar(10000),
 IN amount INT,
 OUT purchase INT,
 OUT expa INT,
 OUT rowt INT)

BEGIN

DECLARE a INT;

SET a = 1;

select sum(s.purchase) into purchase from company c join employee e on c.cid=e.eid left join salary s on s.eid=e.eid where FIND_IN_SET(e.mail,mail); // firs query

IF purchase >= amount THEN

select s.purchase_time, (select sum(purchase) from salary as sp join employee as se on sp.eid=se.eid where FIND_IN_SET(se.mail,mail) and se.eid <= e.eid) into expa, rowt from company c join employee e on c.cid=e.eid left join salary s on s.eid=e.eid where FIND_IN_SET(e.mail,mail) group by c.cid having rowt >= amount order by e.eid ASC limit 1; //second query

ELSEIF purchase < amount THEN

select sum(s.purchase), count(*) into purchase, expa from company c join employee e on c.cid=e.eid left join salary s on s.eid=e.eid where c.createdtime >= start_date;

ENDIF;

END

;;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use subquery in MySQL to solve this issue.

```
select x.purchase_time into expa from (select s.purchase_time, (select sum(purchase) from salary as sp join employee as se on sp.eid=se.eid where FIND_IN_SET(se.mail,mail) and se.eid <= e.eid) as rowt from company c join employee e on c.cid=e.eid left join salary s on s.eid=e.eid where FIND_IN_SET(e.mail,mail) group by c.cid having rowt >= amount order by e.eid ASC limit 1;)x //second query
```